# Select "entities" where only there are several groups of another characteristic (another column)

Tags: python, pandas

*I am sorry in advance because that's very difficult to express well with only one question in a good English for me.*

I use pandas with python.

Let's say for any game (represented by an id) there are several individuals with their characteristics. One of these characteristics is to be in a group (`XL`, `X`, `XS`).

One important thing is, in one game we can have only one group of individuals represented. 
Then in my descriptive statistics, considering **all** the games, the group `XS` is better than `X`.
But I really want to confirm if they really are when they **really face** the group `X` in a game.

Let's see with a `groupby` method on the dataframe:

```
DF.groupby(['ID','GROUP']).mean() #notice the only other column is the score
+---------+-------+---------------+
|   ID    | GROUP | MEAN OF SCORE |
+---------+-------+---------------+
| 1000046 | XS    |          4.50 |
| 1000047 | XS    |          6.41 |
| 1000051 | X     |          3.00 |
|         | XS    |          3.75 |
+---------+-------+---------------+
```

The dataframe is like:

```
+---------+-------+-------+
|   ID    | GROUP | SCORE |
+---------+-------+-------+
| 1000046 | XS    |  5.00 |
| 1000046 | XS    |  5.00 |
| 1000046 | XS    |  4.00 |
| 1000046 | XS    |  4.00 |
| 1000047 | XS    |  6.41 |
| 1000047 | XS    |  6.41 |
| 1000047 | XS    |  6.41 |
| 1000051 | X     |  3.00 |
| 1000051 | X     |  3.00 |
| 1000051 | X     |  3.00 |
| 1000051 | XS    |  3.75 |
| 1000051 | XS    |  3.75 |
| 1000051 | XS    |  3.75 |
+---------+-------+-------+
```

As you can see, `XS` is the only category in some games and it biases my stats understanding.
So I want to select the `ID`s of games which have several categories, as `1000051`.

I had a look on the attribute `groups` of the `groupby` object, the problem is the tuples only have two values `('1000051','X),('1000051','XS')`, and do not gives information if one ID (game) contains more than one group like `('1000051','X','XS')`.

Well, I know I can make an algorithm in order to obtain a `dict` like the following:

```
Ids_groups = {
 '1000046': ['XS'],
 '1000047': ['XS'],
 '1000051' : ['XS','X']
}
```

Then I can keep only the keys and values where `'XS'` is in values (a list) and the length of the values is over 1. Then use the list of keys `['1000051',...]` to select wanted rows of the dataframe.

So I ask you if there is a more clever way to do it, a more efficient one too.

Pandas version: 0.23.4
Python version: 3.7.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

```
df_filtered=df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x: x.GROUP.nunique()>1)
print(df_filtered)

         ID GROUP  SCORE
7   1000051     X   3.00
8   1000051     X   3.00
9   1000051     X   3.00
10  1000051    XS   3.75
11  1000051    XS   3.75
12  1000051    XS   3.75
```

---

Also we can use `Groupby.transform` to performance a [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df_filtered=df[df.groupby('ID').GROUP.transform('nunique')>1]
```

---

```
print(df)

          ID GROUP  SCORE
0   1000046    XS   5.00
1   1000046    XS   5.00
2   1000046    XS   4.00
3   1000046    XS   4.00
4   1000047    XS   6.41
5   1000047    XS   6.41
6   1000047    XS   6.41
7   1000051     X   3.00
8   1000051     X   3.00
9   1000051     X   3.00
10  1000051    XS   3.75
11  1000051    XS   3.75
12  1000051    XS   3.75
```

Comment: The second one is **much** faster. `GroupBy.filter` uses a slow loop :(

Comment: Thank you, I would not find it by myself, especially when the `transform` function of `GroupBy` object is [empty in doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform) .

Answer (score 0):

I would use `nunique()` in order to know how many groups are there per game, afterwards you can use it within a filter function, or simply as an extra variable to perform your calculations:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'ID':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3],'GROUP':['XS','XS','X','XS','XS','XS','XS','XS','X'],'SCORE':[3,4,2,3,4,3,3,2,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df_1 = df.groupby(['ID'],as_index=False).agg({'GROUP':'nunique'})
print(df_1)
```

Output:

```
   ID  GROUP
0   1      2
1   2      1
2   3      2
```

Therefore you know now that for game 1, there were 2 groups participating, for game 2 only 1 and for game 3 there were 2 groups as well.